# find and replace word with elasticsearch [elasticsearch]

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I find and replace partial data in elasticsearch?

I have tried update_by_query. However, it replaces the whole value in a certain field which is not what I am looking for. What I am trying to achieve is to find 'cat' in a sentence and replace it with 'dog'

"this is a cat" ===> "this is a dog"

I have tried the following query:

```
        //     body: {
        //         script: {source: ctx._source.aa = params.term,
        //                 params: {term: dog},
        //                 lang: "painless"
        //         },
        //         query: {term: cat}
        // }};
```

Comment: Duplicated here with answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698187/how-to-replace-string-without-regexp-inside-painless-inline-script-for-aws-elast

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` method in `script` to do this

```
POST {index_name}/{type}/{id}/_update
{
  "script" : { 
    "source": "ctx._source.aa=ctx._source.aa.replace(\"cat\", params.term)",
    "params": { "term": "dog" },
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

NOTE: The script syntax uses Elasticsearch 6.x.x

Comment: Thanks for your help!